# Fully shadowed APK issue

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload both 64bit and 32bit apk's to the application store. So my question is, how do I do it. Initially I tried to upload one after the other (x64 and then x32) as shown in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=rMl_oLlf_g0). However, I was getting an error when I did it for x32, which said that I already had a version 1 (which was when I rolled out the x64 version). So, to solve it, I changed the version number for the x32 to 2 and tried to create a release. However now I'm getting the fully shadowed apk error :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out this answer I recently wrote about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246390/4265103

Comment: @Pierre yes that solved my problem, thanks a lot man :)